# .parents() not work on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying show user details in user list using AJAX JQuery, but it does not work as I need.
It works for my first details in the same `tr`, but doesn't work in the second detail in `td` in the second row. How should I do it properly?

Here is the code:

My view:

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>password</th>
            <th></th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <tr>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$user->password}}</td>
                        <td class="extend-user" data-details="0" data-url="{{route("user", ["id" => $user->id])}}">Details</td>
                        <td id="details">a</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" id="details">a</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </tr>
        @endforeach  
        </tbody>       
    </table>
```

and my script:

```
    $(".extend-user").click(function() {
    var self = this;

    if($(self).data("details")===0)
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: $(self).data("url"),
        data: {
            _token: $("#_token").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(self).parents().find("#details").append(data["name"]);
            //$(self).parent().parent().find("#details").append(data["name"]);
            //$(self).closest('table').find("#details").append(data["name"]);;
            $(self).data("details", "1");
        }
    });
    if($(self).data("details")===1) {
        $(self).data("details", "0");
        $(self).parent().find("p.details").html("");
    }
});
```

Comment: try to use $(self).parent().parent().find("#details").append(data["name"]); by the way the id should be unique in your HTML document itherwise look to use a class because by this way you can not get both of them while they are having the same id

Comment: you have right, I should use CLASS not ID. thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$(self).closest("table").find("#details").append(data["name"]);`

closest finds the closest parent element that you want to find.

Answer (score 0):

replace 
 `$(self).parents().find("#details").append(data["name"]);` 
with

```
$(self).parents('tr').find("#details").append(data["name"]);
```